# How to analyze JVM crash file hs_err_pidXYZ.log

Tags: java, jvm

When working on a webapp in Eclipse and Tomcat (wtp) , tomcat crashes and create a file: hs_err_pid20216.log

I tried to use eclipse MAT to analyse the file but MAT doesn't recognize the file as something it can handle, I tried also DAT and it was the same thing. It won't show in the open file dialog.

What kind of file is it?

What should I use to analyze it?

Do I have to make changes to this file so that it will be possible for these tools to parse it.

The log file is available as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/2350178#file_hs_err_pid20216.log)

UPDATE:

See @Dan Cruz reply for more information on how to deal with hs_err_pidXYZ.log file. For curious, the cause of the crash was Jackson being confused by a cyclic relationship (bidirectional one-to-many) but this is another story...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What kind of file it is?

It's a HotSpot error log file in text format.

> What should I use to analyze it?

Start by downloading the [OpenJDK 6 source bundle](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/). Search through the hotspot `*.cpp` files for strings in the error log. Review the source files for an explanation of what the error log contains.

For example, using OpenJDK 7 sources, you can find `siginfo` (the operating system process signal information) in the `os::print_siginfo()` method of [`os_linux.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp), `Registers` (the CPU registers' values) in the `os::print_context()` method of [`os_linux_x86.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/os_linux_x86.cpp), etc.

> Do I have to make changes to this file sothat it will be possible for these tools to parse it.

That would be impossible since the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) requires a heap file, which the HotSpot error log is not.

Answer (score 10):

https://fastthread.io gives a well descriptive analyze on the file. it just need to upload it and it will give following items:

1. Reason to crash
2. Recommended Solutions
3. Active Thread (when app crashed)
4. Core Dump Location
5. All threads
6. ...

Comment: https://fastthread.io/ does only analyze thread dumps, but not Fatal Error Log files.

Comment: just upload a log file and the site took it and gave some recommendation based on it.

Comment: @Captainju fastthread.io analyzes the hs_err_pid files as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's a text file. Open it in an editor and try to understand what it means.