# How to diagnose the root cause of tomcat crash

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, crash, suse

I have a Tomcat server 7.0.54 running on SUSE Linux 11 SP3, which occasionally crashes.

I checked the `catalina.out` file and found the log `INFO: Stopping service Catalina` which looked like Tomcat got an abnormal shutdown signal. There is no error log before this Stopping log, which is very weird.

It does not look like a JVM crash because it has a process: `pause -> stop -> destroy`. But it seems not to have been shut down by the `shutdown.sh` through the shutdown port normally. Because it would have an important log `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await` if it had been shut down by the shutdown port.

This may have two reasons:

1. `System.exit` was executed. I checked the code and there is nothing of that kind.
2. It got a system signal, e.g. `SIGHUP`.

How to find which signal it got and which program sent the signal?

Any suggestion/comments to find the root cause are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your os log?

Comment: Have you checked the other Tomcat logs?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess Tomcat may be crashing due to insufficient memory. You can use [Eclipse Memory Analysis](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) tool to analyse the heap dump generated.
The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is a fast and feature-rich Java heap analyzer that helps you find memory leaks and reduce memory consumption.

Check [tomcat](http://voiceinitiate.com/tag/the-following-web-applications-have-an-unusually-large-number-of-active-sessions-axl-please-collect-all-of-the-tomcat-logs-for-root-cause-analysis-file-get-activelog-tomcatlogs/) logs thoroughly. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087032/how-to-analyze-jvm-crash-file-hs-err-pidxyz-log), [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html) & [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-memory).

Comment: The voiceinitiate.com link is broken

Comment: The https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html link is broken too.